# Firefox won't 'drive' with Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I've used Firefox with Webdriver on this machine before, but suddenly when I use any code that utilizes Firefox as the driver, Firefox will open and just sit there blankly. Absolutely nothing loads, my program hangs until I close the window at which point it raises the "browser not open" error.

Tried reinstalling. Chrome/IE Drivers work but I don't really want to use them.

Included a pic of exactly what happens when I use any code, for instance

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "http://google.com" 
driver.get(url)
```

Even this gets me nothing.
[image]

Comment: Whats your selenium/firefox version?

Comment: I think it's an issue with firefox version you had been using. You can try a standard version of firefox like 12 , 15 and test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

upgrade to selenium version 2.29.0

```
pip install -U selenium
```

there was a bug fix in the previous version

Comment: Ahhh... haha. The only thing I didn't try. Thanks.

Comment: that's a pretty serious bug if you couldn't do something as simple as getting the initial url!

Comment: Same issue was noticed when I didn't update from 2.42.0 to 2.43.1, so it's kind of universal answer. Thanks.