# Selenium starts but does not load a page

Tags: python, selenium

I am running python 2.7.12 with selenium version 2.53.6 and firefox 49.0. I have looked here for [Selenium WebDriver: Firefox starts, but does not open the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768658/selenium-webdriver-firefox-starts-but-does-not-open-the-url) but the solutions mentioned have not solved my problem.

Are there compatibility issues of which I am unaware? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: may try by downgrading firefox..

Answer (score 1):

you must used Firefox version<=46.0

Answer (score 1):

Download Firefox from this link https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/win64-EME-free/en-GB/Firefox%20Setup%2046.0.1.exe and then try again

Answer (score 1):

For higher version of Firefox either use Selenium 3.0.x or use `geckodriver`.

Comment: In my case - Selenium 3.0.1 and Firefox 49 - it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

i am also facing the same problem. I downgraded the Firefox to 47.0.1 and it works

Answer (score 1):

As you are using selenium version 2.53.6 .So it is not compatible with firefox version 49.0.

You should downgrade your firefox version to <=46

Download older version of firefox from the below address:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox.